# does virtual memory need to be contiguous on disk?

Tags: linux, ram, virtual-memory

I was reading a textbook which says that:
[image]

> If the valid bit is set, the address field indicates the start of the corresponding physical page in DRAM where the virtual page is cached. If the valid bit is not set, then a null address indicates that the virtual page has not yet been allocated. Otherwise, the address points to the start of the virtual page on disk.

My question is, does each page tabe entry(PTE) need to be match the same offset one in disk? for example, `PTE 1` has `VP 1` in physical memory, but can `PTE 1` originally mapped to `VP 3`? or `PTE 1` has to map `VP 1`,  `PTE 2` has to map `VP 2`,  `PTE 3` has to map `VP 3` and so on?

if `PTE x` has to map `VP x`, then why when valid bit is not set then the address points to the start of the virtual page on disk? can't we use the offset `x` in `PTE x` to infer that it maps to `VP x`?

Comment: `PTE x` just maps to `VP x` by definition. VP1..7 does not need to be contiguous on disk.

Comment: I think it's misleading to show "disk address" as being in the page table.  In a non-toy operating system, more likely it's an index into some kernel data structure that is used to find where the page resides on disk.  Remember that the process of swapping in pages is done in software, not in hardware, so it can be as complex as the OS designers want it to.  In particular the OS can certainly keep track of a page's data being spread across the disk in an arbitrary non-contiguous way, if that's how it's designed to work.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge so the index of kernel data structure can be inferred 'x' in 'PTE x', there is no need to store this index in PTE, PTE only need to store physical page number, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility.  I don't know off the top of my head how Linux does it.